# WELD-000710: Cannot inject HttpServletRequest outside of a Servlet request

Tags: java, wildfly, java-ee-7

I have abstract class in java ee application with injected HttpServletRequest:

```
abstract class MyRestClientAbstract {

    @Inject
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    public void doStuff() {
        /// do stuff with request...
    }
```

and I use this "doStuff" in Feature calls, which are used by other "Services", that are not a "Controllers" in a spring-like understanding.

And when I call doStuff() I got an exceeption:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalStateException: WELD-000710: Cannot inject HttpServletRequest outside of a Servlet request
   at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.ee.HttpServletRequestBean.newInstance(HttpServletRequestBean.java:53)
   at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.ee.HttpServletRequestBean.newInstance(HttpServletRequestBean.java:40)
   at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.AbstractDecorableBuiltInBean.create(AbstractDecorableBuiltInBean.java:52)
   at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
   at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
   at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
   at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
   at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:99)
   at org.jboss.weldx.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest$$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getHeader(Unknown Source)
   at com.systematic.site.commons.restClients.RestClientAbstract.createRequestBuilderWithAuthHeader(RestClientAbstract.java:36)
   at com.systematic.site.commons.restClients.RestClient.lambda$getListAsync$2(RestClient.java:75)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:69)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:77)
   at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onNext(Subscribers.java:235)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoAfterTerminate$1.onNext(OperatorDoAfterTerminate.java:50)
   at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276)
   at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
   at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
   at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
   at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:138)
   at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:129)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
   at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10150)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeUsing.call(OnSubscribeUsing.java:94)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeUsing.call(OnSubscribeUsing.java:32)
   at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10150)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
   at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10150)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
   at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10150)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
   at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10150)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFilter.call(OnSubscribeFilter.java:45)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFilter.call(OnSubscribeFilter.java:30)
   at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10150)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFilter.call(OnSubscribeFilter.java:45)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFilter.call(OnSubscribeFilter.java:30)
   at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10246)
   at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10213)
   at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10053)
```

I've tried to change @Inject to @Context, in that way I got NPE, because request is null.

javaee-api:7.0.jar is used.

P.S. maybe problem, that Services, that use MyRestClientAbstract, they are @Singleton[s]. And when ServletRequest trying to be injected, it failed for singletons?

Comment: The lifecycle of HttpServletRequest is managed by the web container, not the CDI container. Therefore you cannot inject it into a non web bean.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ? Trying to access current HTTP request in your API?

Comment: You mention an abstract class, but not where you then try and use it